# The compiler bug? Returning std::vector and std::string in std::tuple. But I got strange values

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector, auto, stdtuple

I would like to return multiple values and declare that function using `auto`.

But that does not work well. Values can not be returned correctly. It was overwritten.

I try to execute following functions `f1`~`f3`. Those function should return vector and string in tuple.
But only `f3` works well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

auto f1(){
    std::vector<double> v(10, 0);
    std::string s = "hello";
    return std::forward_as_tuple(v, s);
}

auto f2(){
    std::vector<double> v(10, 0);
    return std::forward_as_tuple(v, "hello");
}

std::tuple<std::vector<double>, std::string> f3(){
    std::vector<double> v(10, 0);
    std::string s = "hello";
    return std::forward_as_tuple(v, s);   
}
int main(void){
    //change the function
    //auto [vec, str] = f1();
    //auto [vec, str] = f2();
    auto [vec, str] = f2();

    for (auto e : vec){
        std::cout << "vec : " << e << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "str : " << str << std::endl;
}
```

You can also execute this program at online compiler wandbox from this [link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iHPsZy4FkpeBNxGa).

- `f1()` causes an segmentation fault.
- `f2()` returns wrong values in `std::vector`. It seems random number.
- `f3()` returns all values correctly.

Why does this problem occur?
Is it impossible to return multiple values and declare that function using `auto`?

Comment: Quoting cppreference.com: “Constructs a tuple of **references** to the arguments” (emphasis mine). You’re returning dangling references.

Comment: -> `return std::make_tuple(std::move(v), std::move(s));`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem occurs because `std::forward_as_tuple` returns references to local variables - the return type is `tuple<vector<double>&,string&>`.

The first two functions produce undefined behaviour.

The third one works because you explicitly return by value, although the forwarding doesn't work because you did not move the l-values so they get copied into the returned tuple.

The correct way to return a tuple is just:

```
return std::tuple{std::move(vec),std::move(str)};
```

Comment: In the third one, the forward **does** work, but it is superfluous because the values get copied.

Comment: @Eljay Fair enough, I wanted to say that it does not work as OP intended because forwarding l-values results in copies instead of moves.